# Infinispan many-to-one cache using pool of objects rather than creating new ones?

Tags: caching, replication, infinispan

I have a use case where I receive some data quite frequently that I need to cache with Infinispan (in a replicated cluster in library mode/in-process) where the data is often very similar but the amount different keys is much larger than the amount of possible different associated data.

I am worried about the number of data objects being created/replicated unnecessarily which are mostly duplicates of each other under different keys.

Is my only option to break my cache into two? e.g.

`key -> data hash -> data`

My only problem with this is the possibility of the `key -> data hash` being replicated to the rest of the cluster before the `data has -> data` cache. I need the `data` to be there by the time the `key` is replicated (as I handle that event).

Or are there any other options available such as intercepting a cache insert to use a pool of these data objects?

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature that would let you de-duplicate the data, so yes, you need to break that into two caches. You could write [your own interceptor](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#custom_interceptors_chapter), but there be lions. Would you iterate through all local entries to find a match?

If you use non-transactional cache with synchronous replication, you can just update the `dataId -> data` cache first, and then the `key -> dataId`. By the time the second operation is invoked the first write is replicated to all nodes.